# Name in @OrderColumn annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring and web development in Java in general.
I read Hibernate/JPA 2.0 documentation and I know that in annotation
`@OrderColumn` there is an argument `name`.
`@OrderColumn(name = "name_of_the_column_that_we_would_like_to_order")` our collection.

However, I've seen some other names - e.g. *pos* and *nbr*. I am guessing that these are suggesting that it should be ordered by position in table or by number(nbr) or by ID or something, unfortunately I couldn't find an exact answer, only some examples without database example.

**EDIT**: Also, if there is any other example of something similar to this *pos* and *nbr* it would be nice to be shared. I am guessing *nbr* and *pos* are some reserved words that somehow jpa knows how it should receive and order data.

**EDIT2**:

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name = "question")
public class Question {

```
/**
 * serialVersionUID
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7677167590736866885L;

/**
 * Content of the question
 */
@Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
@Pattern(regexp = "^(?=\\s*\\S).*$")
private String content;

/**
 * Possible answers to the question
 */
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "question_answer", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
"question_id"))
@OrderColumn(name = "nbr")
@Valid
private List<Answer> answers;

/**
 * Category of the question
 */
@ManyToOne(optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = true)
private Category category;
```

Pay attention on this part:

```
/**
 * Possible answers to the question
 */
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "question_answer", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
"question_id"))
@OrderColumn(name = "nbr")
@Valid
private List<Answer> answers;
```

However, in the base there's no column named *nbr*.

Here's the picture of Question table

[image: Question table columns]

Here's the picture of Answer table

[image: Answer's table columns]

`category_id`is foreign key, ID of category where this question belongs.

Comment: and "Answer" is what ? an Entity? any old class? The order column is GENERATED BY YOUR JPA PROVIDER. and where is the "question_answer" table? the one that contains the List!!!

Comment: Answer is an Entity, obviously.
There's no question_answer table, since it's not `ManyToMany` relationship.

Comment: If something is an ENTITY then you cannot use `@ElementCollection` (obviously), you use `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` (and `@JoinTable` instead of `@CollectionTable`). And yes there is that table since you SPECIFIED it in your metadata!

Comment: Answer is an entity. It has its own table in db, but it's not independent, it is `@Embeddable`, because answer cannot exist if there's no question that it belongs to.

Comment: either way, the JOIN TABLE exists, because that is the table that the elements are EMBEDDED into. `@Embeddable` does not have its own table

Answer (score 0):

```
@OrderColumn(name="MY_ORDER_COLUMN")
List myList;
```

will create an ordering column of name `MY_ORDER_COLUMN` in either the join table (if modelling the List field via a join table), or in the table of the element.

There are no secret values of that name, it is just [what you want to call the column](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/mapping.html#one_many_list)! The `@OrderColumn` will contain integer values of the positions of the elements 0, 1, 2, ... etc